# Running Values not working

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am creating a report with Running Value. How do I do A-B=C, C-D=E, E-F=G as show in the image below:

[image]

I tried `=Fields!Parent_Amount.Value-RunningValue(Fields!PO_Total_Amount.Value,Sum,"Project_Name")` which doesn't work. The section in Yellow is a parent group and blue is a child group.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your dataset? Also a screenshot of your table could be useful to provide an answer

Comment: I think it can be done using custom code, share a sample of your dataset and a sample of the expected result in order to help you.